# stationary reflection in $[\kappa]^\omega$

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, forcing, large-cardinals

It is well-known that the following reflection principle is consistent relative to a supercompact:

> For all $\kappa \geq \omega_2$ and all stationary $S \subseteq [\kappa]^\omega$, there is $X \subseteq \kappa$ such that $\omega_1 \subseteq X$, $|X| = \omega_1$, and $S \cap [X]^\omega$ is stationary.

Let us say $Refl(\kappa,\mu)$ holds when:

> For all stationary $S \subseteq [\kappa]^\omega$, there is $X \subseteq \kappa$ such that $\mu \subseteq X$, $|X| = \mu$, and $S \cap [X]^\omega$ is stationary.

If $\mu$ is regular and there is a supercompact above $\mu$, then by Levy-collapsing that supercompact to be $\mu^+$, we get a model of $(\forall \kappa \geq \mu^+)Refl(\kappa,\mu)$.

**Question:** Is $Refl(\aleph_{\omega+1},\aleph_\omega)$ consistent?

Comment: That reflection principle implies the version of Strong Chang's Conjecture you asked me about.  Though I guess you probably already know that, and maybe that's why you asked the question...

Comment: @SeanCox: We might need to go to $Refl(|H_{\aleph_{\omega+2}}|,\aleph_\omega)$ to deduce the version of SCC.

Comment: Yes, you're right.